# How does event handler work inside a function?

Tags: javascript

Okay, So I have a habit of over thinking. 
While I am relatively new to javascript and my instructor might cover this later, I am having a tough time understanding **How does event handler work inside a function**

For example, I am attaching multiple events handler to an object.

```
function addListenerMulti(element, eventNames, listener){
  var events = eventNames.split('');
   for (var i=0, i<events.length; i++) {
      element.addEventListener(events[i], listener);
    }
}

addListenerMulti(color, 'change paste keyup', function(){
```

Now when I fire an event, for say I press and let go a key. How will the addListenMulti function trigger?

Comment: That looks like it works. It should fire the function you pass into addListenerMulti for any of the events, such as key up. However, there are issues such as incorrect for loop syntax. it should be (var i=0; i <events.length; i++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains syntax errors, although the logic is correct.

event handlers work by calling a function when an event is fired. for example *on* keyup, the callback function passed to the event listener will be fired. *on* keyup event will only fire for the element of which you set an event listener of 'keyup'. 'change' event is usually fired on blur, if the input has been changed. 'paste' is, you guessed it, fired when text is pasted into an input with type="text". Not all elements will fire 'changed'. Specific details can be seen here:

addEventListener:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Event (this is the first argument in the callback function):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

However your code could be improved as it is unecessary to format a string like that and split it, just put each event name in an array as so:

```js
var color = document.getElementById("color-element");
['change', 'paste', 'keyup'].forEach(function(evt){
  color.addEventListener(evt, function(e){
    console.log("Event", evt, "fired");
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="color-element" type="text">
```

This could be improved further, by abstractifying the code, as you did so it is easier to use the code again.

```js
var color = document.getElementById("color-element");
var events = ['change', 'paste', 'keyup'];
var eventCallback = function(e){
  console.log("Event", e.type, "fired");
}
function addListenerMulti(element, events, callback){
  events.forEach(function(evt){
    element.addEventListener(evt, callback);
  });
}
addListenerMulti(color, events, eventCallback);
```

```html
<input id="color-element" type="text">
```

and more concise, with ES6 - plus error handling for debugging...

```js
const color = document.getElementById("color-element");
const events = ['change', 'paste', 'keyup'];
const eventCallback = function(e){
  console.log("Event", e.type, "fired");
}
function addListenerMulti(element, events, callback){
  if(typeof callback !== 'function'){
    throw new Error(`no callback function provided (of type ${typeof callback})`);
  }
  if(!element){
    throw new Error("no element provided");
  }
  if(!events){
    throw new Error("no events provided");
  }
  events.forEach(evt => {
    element.addEventListener(evt, callback);
  });
}
addListenerMulti(color, events, eventCallback);
```

```html
<input id="color-element" type="text">
```

Answer (score 4):

> How will the addListenMulti function trigger?

It won't, it's done its job. The function the event triggers is the function you passed *to* `addListenMulti`, which is the event handler. `addListenMulti` is just a function hooking the handler up to the element.

---

Side note: You have two bugs in that code:

1. In the `for`, you have a `,` instead of `;` after `var i=0`
2. `.split('')` should be `.split(' ')` (with a space)

---

I don't think you are, but if you're wondering how to know *which* event triggered the handler, it's available as the `type` property on the object the handler receives as its first argument.

```
addListenerMulti(color, 'change paste keyup', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type); // Will be "change" or "paste" or "keyup"
});
```

```js
function addListenerMulti(element, eventNames, listener){
    var events = eventNames.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        element.addEventListener(events[i], listener);
    }
}
var color = document.getElementById("color");
addListenerMulti(color, 'change paste keyup', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type); // Will be "change" or "paste" or "keyup"
});
```

```html
<input id="color" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just to clarify:**

```
addListenerMulti(color, 'change paste keyup', function() {});
```

That call above it's just binding the events to a specific element and nothing else, its job ends right in that moment.

> Of course, that's assuming that call it's called "programmatically" and not executed from a triggered event.

What actually will be triggered is the handler from the bound events `change paste keyup`.

```
function addListenerMulti(element, eventNames, listener){
  var events = eventNames.split('');
   for (var i=0, i<events.length; i++) {
                                          +---- This is what actually 
                                          |     will be triggered
                                          v
      element.addEventListener(events[i], listener);
    }
}
```